# Перемещение элементов и их возврат на исходную позицию jQuery

Tags: html, css, jquery

Есть кнопка и текст привязанный к ней. Необходимо написать код, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, текст сдвигался направо на 35px, и при повторном нажатии возвращался на исходную позицию. В голове понимаю что надо добавить класс с новой позицией, и по кнопке добавлять или исключать его, но выполнить не могу

```
$('#button3').click(function () {
            $('.three').css({
                'position': 'relative',
                'left': '35px'
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  $(".text").toggleClass("textMove")

})
```

```css
.textMove {
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, repudiandae, harum! Inventore veniam aperiam recusandae illum laboriosam accusamus, quia voluptatum obcaecati aliquid voluptate tempore delectus eum, quam sed, facilis a cumque harum possimus
  dignissimos nihil asperiores, nisi blanditiis aliquam optio amet. Amet totam rerum earum reprehenderit impedit, harum, a iusto.</div>
<button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
```

Можно так, хотя очень не оптимально, и непонятно зачем вам это надо

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае вам нужно как-то проверять состояние на текущий момент и относительно него менять.
Допустим мы будем проверять, есть ли отступ в `35px`, если нет то выставить

```js
let text = $('.three');

$('#button3').click(function () {
  let check = text.css('left') === '35px'; // Если установлено left: 35px то true, иначе false
  // Если текст не содержит отступ, то мы его добавляем, иначе возвращаем значения по умолчанию
  text.css({
    'position': check === false ? 'relative' : '',
    'left': check === false ? '35px' : ''
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, repudiandae, harum! Inventore veniam aperiam recusandae illum laboriosam accusamus, quia voluptatum obcaecati aliquid voluptate tempore delectus eum, quam sed, facilis a cumque harum possimus
  dignissimos nihil asperiores, nisi blanditiis aliquam optio amet. Amet totam rerum earum reprehenderit impedit, harum, a iusto.</div>
<button id="button3">Кнопка</button>
```